# how to generate testing report using selenium ide for php

Tags: selenium

I record a test in selenium IDE and generate test report by installing test result addons.
test report is generated in table format but it did not display it will succeed or not.
Test report shows only test case pane in table format

how to generate detail report of test case using selenium IDE for php

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE isn't focused on PHP. I prefer to use Selenium in combination with PHPUnit, which makes Selenium's functionality available within PHP testing.

You can export recorded Selenium IDE tests with a special PHP formatter add-on and so integrate your Selenium tests into PHP testing.

If you like to have detailed test results, use PHPUnit's logging features. PHPUnit can log testing results as several formats (e.g. JUnit XML, TAP).

But one last suggestion: Use [Selenium Builder](http://sebuilder.github.io/se-builder/) which is much more comfortable and powerful than Selenium IDE ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you simply need to get addon selenium php formatter to your firefox then you will get option in export as test case -> phpunit.

Answer (score 0):

you simply need to get addon as selenium php formatter to your firefox then you will get a option as export as test case->phpunit